# How can I give permission to a user to access a table in a dataset in BigQuery and have the dataset appear in the project?

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset, google-iam

I would like to give access to a list of tables in a dataset (not all tables) to a user.

Here is my bigquery architecture :

```
|Project
  |-Dataset
    |-table1
    |-table2
```

Let's say I want my user to see only table1.

1. If I add a data viewer IAM permission to my user at the dataset level, the hierarchical policy causes tables 1 and 2 to inherit the IAM permission, which is not good because he can see table2
2. If I add a data viewer IAM permission to my user at the table level, the user can access the table1 via a link or query but ***cannot see the dataset in the BiqQuery UI***

Is there a way to make table 1 and the dataset appear without table 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good solution:

- Add an IAM metadataviewer at the dataset level.
- Add an IAM dataviewer at the table level.

The client can see both tables (1 and 2) but can only access data from table1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GRANT` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-control-language#grant_statement) to give permission to a specific table to a specific user using BigQuery. You have to grant the role that you want if it is a viewer, it would be like:

```
GRANT `roles/bigquery.dataViewer`
ON TABLE my_dataset.my_table
TO "user:user@domain.com"
```

But the role that you are searching for is [bigquery.metadataViewer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#:%7E:text=BigQuery%20Metadata%20Viewer) this role granted to a dataset will provide access to read metadata as well as list the tables.
This role can also be applied to a table/view so the user will have to explicitly list the permission for the tables they wish to see and not the whole dataset.

```
GRANT `roles/bigquery.metadataViewer`
ON TABLE `my_dataset._my_table`
TO "user:user@domain.com"
```

Additionally, the Second user can pin the project. This would let him see the project, the dataset and the tables where he has access.